# Efficiently troubleshooting a circuit card

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, soldering

I will start off by explaining and giving some background. I cannot share any images of the circuit card in question because a security clearance is required to do so. I work in the US military fixing a variety of items, mainly circuit cards. I was given rudimentary training on troubleshooting because most of the stuff I work on has already been troubleshot and common faults have been identified.

However, I am working on something new and some guidance on what to do or good resources to look at would be much appreciated. Like the people before me who streamlined the job for me, I wish to do the same for those after me with this new gear.

On to the problem. The problem affects two circuit cards. I’ll call them CC1 and CC2. The fault that occurs in CC1 is that one of three capacitors will burn, easy fix I replace them and the individual CC1 works fine. I believe the source of the problem is on CC2. When I put a fixed CC1 back into the unit without replacing CC2 with a known good the capacitors will burn again.

More information on CC2, I’ve heard been referred to as the “Power Card”. It connects directly to the battery via a ribbon cable. CC2 is also an SMD, with components on both sides. Over 200 components. The entire unit fails to power on when CC2 has visible defects. Whenever it does have them, it burns, they are located toward the upper middle portion of the card. I do have access to known goods and the means to create a test routine, measuring and recording the signals of all the components but as stated it has more than 200 components.

Given the nature of my job and the limited time I have available to do this, it could cost me weeks to just develop the test routine alone. It’s something I’m willing to do but only if I can’t find a more effective way of possibly finding a common fault.

Any and all help is much appreciated, and sorry if my post is hard to read English is my 3rd language and I never really understood commas.

Edit: I should’ve added my guess to the problem and I would assume something is causing the power card to not be able to regulate the current as it was intended to do. From my understanding, if a capacitor receives too much voltage it will break and voltage is current x resistance. The only part that confuses me is that the card has what I believe are fuses and they are still intact. Unless my understanding of capacitors and fuses is wrong (very possible as I’ve only just recently started learning about electronics because of this job that I was randomly assigned) then the fuses should’ve done their job and broken correct? Or would they have a different purpose on this card?

Comment: You work for the US military and they’ve assigned you to fix what could be very expensive gear. Something sounds very wrong here. I’d be pushing it up the chain.

Comment: Fuses lack specificity. They are usually to prevent fire in the case of short circuit. In order to make sure that fuses don't fail during normal operation, they will rarely prevent over voltage or overheating.

Comment: What type of capacitor is the one that fails? In what way does it "burn" - goes brown, goes bang with flames, or something else?

Comment: @Kartman it’s actually something that’s very common in the military lol. I know plenty of 19 year olds in charge of fixing parts of fighter jets and those are worth millions. Personally I’ve fixed EOD robots but that isn’t classified and I can get my hands on schematics

Comment: Rah, you're being paid to fix this. If actually need someone to sign an NDA / get ITAR/clearance paperwork done, then seriously: You are not the right one for this particular job, you need to escalate that, and subcontract to someone with clearance. I'm all for helping people for free (we are all here :) ), but it has limits. "I'm a defense contractor and know I can't give you relevant details" very clearly is such a limit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I believe they are tantalum caps 100uF. i can double check when I go to work tomorrow (I am stationed in Japan).  No noise is made the unit just heats up and when I open it the capacitor is burnt black, sometimes the damage is more minor causing it to chip and crack slightly but still rendering it useless. However sometimes when I use a cap reader on some of the caps that remain somewhat intact the cap reader measures its capacitance to be very high to a point where my reader can’t display how much. I don’t know if that’s normal for a broken cap

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh I see the confusion. My apologies. I have a security clearance, I am allowed to work on these systems. I am just not allowed to take pictures of them to share online or take these circuit cards outside of my shop. Our warrant contract with the company that provides these systems expired and they also don’t make more of these circuit cards apparently and that leaves me to fix them

Comment: @Rah I'm not confused about that. It's just that you're asking for help on something you can't show – that won't work.

Comment: Tantalum capacitors tend to burn or go bang when exposed to a voltage above their rating.  Check the output voltages from CC2.  Check the voltage on the burned capacitor on a bad CC1 when connected to a bad CC2.

Comment: @MarcusMüller and the over arching theme for my post is how to troubleshoot. I’m not specifically asking for an answer because if I can’t fix it with all the gear and information provided to me how can I expect people on the internet to do it for me with almost nothing. To re iterate I’m asking how should I go about troubleshooting because I was given excellent training in regards to soldering and wiring but basically none with troubleshooting. I added all the extra information for context and maybe narrow down what avenues of information I should be looking for.

Comment: @JRE I usually don’t work on anything while powered on, but this is something I haven’t tried so I will definitely give this a shot thank you. I usually don’t because it’s kind of hard to set these up so they can be powered while the cards are accessible

Comment: Tantalum capacitors can fail on too fast rising voltage = too high initial charge current. This can occur even if the voltage is within the rated range. Put an aluminum polymer capacitor in this position and watch the voltages.

Comment: What is a "circuit card"? Do you mean a PCB?

Answer (score 3):

I can give you a quick diagnosis, and I'm quite certain it's correct.

A fault on CC2 is providing a voltage which is too high, and feeding that voltage to CC1. The high voltage is beyond the ratings of the capacitors on CC1, and they are failing. They are failing open.

Your required approach is also clear.

You need to take the issue to your boss, tell him it's beyond your pay grade and you weren't trained to operate at this level, and he needs to find somebody, like an electronics technician, who can do the job. Bluntly, and I'm trying to be nice, you are out of your depth and you need to stop trying to be a hero.

Your edit gives further evidence that you just don't have the training and knowledge to tackle this. Caps fail when their voltage is too high. Fuses fail when their current is too high. Voltage is not (always) current. Most likely, when the caps fail they produce a current spike which only lasts until the  caps fail open. Fuses don't respond to narrow current spikes - it's not what they are designed for. Unless they are fast-blow units. You don't say which kind you have.

Another problem you have is that it's perfectly possible that failing units on CC2 are being caused by a component which is not, itself, burning up. And mapping voltages without determining the underlying circuit topology and operation is not likely to produce useful results. It's one thing to determine which voltages are off, but that doesn't tell you what they mean.

If, for some reason, you feel you need to do it yourself, your best bet is to bite the bullet and replace every component on CC2.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nobody higher than me to take this to lol. I am the most qualified repair technician in my shop. If I can’t fix it my shop just says unrepairable and sends it to be destroyed. CC2 admittedly is a less common fault in these units it just bothers me that no one knows the root, we know it for all the other common faults these systems have, not CC2. I’ve run the numbers and if I can find a way for my marines to identify bad CC2s and fix them it ups our maintenance output by over 10 percent. Over ambitious? Maybe but I have to try, especially since learning is kinda fun.

Comment: Thank you for the advice though! Will try it out

Comment: Also as you said I clearly don’t know enough about electronics, I started learning admittedly about few days ago when I realized the potential boost in maintenance from learning this. Up to this point I was just a maintenance monkey, fix common faults, replace components, read maintenance manuals, don’t think just do. So yes I haven’t even had to troubleshoot that much to do my job very effectively. But I am very motivated to learn and with that I would like to ask for any resources you would recommend like books or videos that could help me learn about troubleshooting and circuit cards?

Comment: Well, in that case, the first step should be to get a new board. But don't destroy the bad one. Instead, use it as a learning tool. Remove each component (keeping track of which is which!) and measure its value. For undamaged parts, you may be able to simply read the designations. With all the parts off, start mapping the circuit, keeiing in mind that there may well be internal layers. Once you've mapped the connections, use that information to recreate the schematic, and start studying it. And yes, this will be a big project, but you have all the ime in the woirld.

Comment: The trick will be in recreating the damaged parts, but you can refer to good boards as your guide. Unless CC2 has been repeatedly revised, in which case you'll need to put on your thinking cap.

Comment: However, a caution. If you get too independent you can get yourself into trouble. For instance, let's say you figure out how to fix a board when you are expected to just swap in a new one. Should you do it? Don't do it on your own. Are you using mil-spec replacement parts? Is your soldering technique up to the required standards? Did you replace the conformal coating? (Note that if you don't, the circuit may fail in some circumstances.) Are you sure you know how to test the final board properly? Keep in mind that if an aircraft dies and the cause is failure of a board you repaired ...

Comment: I admire your ambition and your willingness to go the next mile. But be aware that things can seem to be needlessly cumbersome when there is actually a good reason. As for learning, on-line university courses can be good. The MIT stuff is excellent, but be warned that the image "trying to take a drink of water from a fire hose" applies. More informally, get hold of Horowitz "The Art of Electronics" and start studying.

Comment: As for my earlier suggestion that yor dissect a bad board, a few seconds' reflection suggests that you will be required to turn in the bad one so that it can be repaired at a higher echelon. Silly me.

Comment: Yes. If there is one thing I am certain of it is my soldering ability and the equipment used to test the final fixed units. I was sent to a course to learn how to solder to a very high standard and it’s only gotten better because it’s all I really do at work. I don’t work on anything crazy like aircraft but I appreciate the concern! I actually just asked my higher up, I was fairly certain I was only not allowed to share pictures and schematics of the cards and I was right so I am allowed to talk about what I work on. They are just radios lol.

Comment: "Just radios"? Tell that to some poor grunt who's trying to call in air support.

Comment: If it’s one I fixed he’s definitely getting his air support lmao thanks again man I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 2):

1. Divide and conquer.  You have a point where something is wrong (capacitor on CC1.) Somewhere between that capacitor and the input to CC2 is an error. You already know that the source of the problem is on CC2 - you said that a bad CC2 will kill each CC1 that you connect to it.  You've reduced your problem by half.  Work the same way on CC2 - find the output from CC2 that goes to CC1, then find out where it comes from on CC2.  Reduce the problem by steps.
2. Use known facts to find hints.  There's a capacitor on a CC1 that burns when a CC2 kills it.  That capacitor is a tantalum capacitor.  Tantalum capacitors don't like over voltage - they short and burn out.  From that, it seems you are looking for something delivering a voltage that is too high.
3. CC2 is a “Power Card” - it regulates the voltage from the battery.  From that you can figure that one of the voltage outputs is too high.
4. Get out the schematic of CC1 and CC2.  Find the output on CC2 that connects to the capacitor on CC1 that burns out.
5. You now know which voltage regulator is bad on CC2.
6. Figure out how to repair or replace the regulator on CC2.

You **must** have schematic diagrams of the two boards.  If you can't get them, then you will have to do your best to draw them from the boards.  If you aren't allowed to have schematics of the equipment, then you shouldn't be working on that equipment.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I’ll try this out when I get the chance. Isolating the fault in CC2 is a side project if I’m being honest. It’s not something that I have to figure out in order to keep my shops maintenance production flowing it is just something I would love to figure out and learn more about as a whole. Thanks again man

Answer (score 1):

Nobody here can help with your specific problem unless you provide details and, you are not going to do that for sensible reasons so, from comments you said this: -

> *the over arching theme for my post is how to troubleshoot. I’m not
> specifically asking for an answer because if I can’t fix it with all
> the gear and information provided to me how can I expect people on the
> internet to do it for me with almost nothing. To re iterate I’m asking
> how should I go about troubleshooting because I was given excellent
> training in regards to soldering and wiring but basically none with
> troubleshooting.*

[image]

Image from [5 Steps to Troubleshooting That Will Fix Just About Anything](https://limblecmms.com/blog/what-is-troubleshooting/)

Troubleshooting is something that you can get trained on. There are books available and, I'm sure there are training courses. Well, there were for me back in the late 1970s but, it does revolve around the picture above AND understanding the circuits you are working on. If you can't read the schematic and understand the components then you can't troubleshoot effectively.

Comment: I don’t know why the company refuses to give us the schematics when I am allowed to dissect these cards as much as I want and make my own schematics. I am just not allowed to share them or take them out of the shop. 

I will definitely look into your link thank you very much! Is there any books that you recommend to help learn about troubleshooting and circuit cards?

Comment: Any books I had are long gone. I found this on the web during a quick search but, if you don't have schematics then you can't troubleshoot properly and, I wouldn't expect a military operation to be based around compromises in this area.

Comment: Another general list of rules I have found useful is covered in the book [Debugging: The 9 Indispensable Rules for Finding Even the Most Elusive Software and Hardware Problems](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0814474578/debuggingrule-20)